# Tailwind CSS fallback for new screen length types such as "lvh", "svh"

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I wrote `tailwind.config.js` as belows to use new css length types such as "lvh", "svh".

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        "screen": "100dvh",
        "screen-small": "100svh",
        "screen-large": "100lvh"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then it successfully exports

```css
.h-screen {
    height: 100dvh;
}
```

But I want to get with fallback properties like

```css
.h-screen {
  height: 100vh; /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */
  height: 100dvh;
}
```

Is there any nice way to export fallback properties with Tailwind CSS?

I had no idea to try

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pass an array as property

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        screen: ['100vh /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */', '100dvh'],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will generate

```css
.h-screen {
  height: 100vh /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */;
  height: 100dvh;
}
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/C1O5FqtQXP?file=config)

Note: I'm not 100% sure it is supposed way to do it as editor shows error because we are passing not string but array of strings.

Another way is to create [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-custom-utilities) with layer

```css
@layer utilities {
  .h-my-screen {
    height: 100vh; /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */
    height: 100dvh;
  }
}
```

In case if you wish to use reserved `h-screen` name approach is similar but it will stack default (100vh) and new value (100dvh) in correct order you need - but it is just coincidence

```css
@layer utilities {
  .h-screen {
    height: 100dvh;
  }
}
```

Same thing using [Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#writing-plugins)

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  // ...

  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addBase, addComponents, addUtilities, theme }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.h-screen': {
          height: '100dvh',
        }
      })
    })
  ],
}
```

Created both way utility `h-screen` will now generate

```css
.h-screen {
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100dvh;
}
```

Note: when using JS syntax object CANNOT contain similar keys (`height` in your case) but it may accept an array of values in defined order

```js
// Wrong
addUtilities({
  '.h-my-screen': {
    height: '100vh /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */',
    height: '100dvh',
  }
})

// Correct
addUtilities({
  '.h-my-screen': {
    height: ['100vh /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */', '100dvh'],
  }
})
```

Comment: For min-h-screen add

```
minHeight: {
    screen: ["100vh /* fallback for Opera, IE and etc. */", "100dvh"],
}
```